# Can we write a SQL query to first order the table alphabetically and have a serial number to it so we can use that serial number for other things

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am developing a website using VB ASP.NET and SQL. I want to create a function on scroll to load more usernames, but for that I need a serial number to pass a value on scroll to load the next user.

But by ordering it alphabetically it ruins the serial number order.

So can I write a query which can first create ordered table and have a unique id to it so I can use that to pass on.

This is my query:

```
select top {0} 
   p.user_id, p.username, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.comp_name 
from 
   v_master_user p     
where 
   p.access_level < 6 
   and user_id > {1} 
order by 
   p.firstname ASC
```

In this I have to pass last value of `user_id`

Comment: http://www.openwinforms.com/row_number_to_sql_select.html

Comment: Even if you can, you need to carefully consider what you want to do if something else causes an insert or delete to occur on the table whilst you're doing this paging.

Comment: You can also use common table expression (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to order table and then use Row_Number() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get unique ID.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Comment: Thank you so much first comment worked .. i cant mark as answer right now.. it was my first question

Comment: `Top {0}` and `user_id > {1}` looks like you are using string formatting to build your query. You really should be using parametrized queries. The first can be replaced with `Top (@count)` (you need the parenthesis to use the parameter) and the second `user_id > @userId`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top {0} 
   p.user_id, p.username, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.comp_name 
from 
   v_master_user p     
where 
   p.access_level < 6 
   and user_id > {1} AND ROW BETWEEN (@StartRowIndex + 1) AND @EndRowIndex
order by 
   p.firstname ASC
```

It will be something like this. You can specify the start and end index.